# why may the type of interface not be respected when all properties are optional?

Tags: typescript, interface

Why this doesn't trigger Typescript compilation error ?

```
interface Test{
    blabla?:string,
    foo?:number
}
let bad:Test = 1;
```

How can we force compilation error in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When all properties are optional it means that an empty object (`{}`) will also satisfy the type.
Because your `Test` can be an empty object then anything can be used as `Test`:

```
let a1 = "string" as Test;
let a2 = true as Test;
let a3 = [1, 2] as Test;
let a4 = { key: "value" } as Test;
let a5 = function() { } as Test;
```

The only way to make it work is to add at least one non-optional property to the `Test` interface.

This is because typescript is [based on structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), meaning that the compiler compares the type structure instead of the type name.
For empty objects, all other "structures" fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `[k: string]: any` to your Interface:

```ts
interface Test{
    blabla?:string;
    foo?:number;
    [k: string]: any
}

let bad:Test = 1; // Type '1' is not assignable to type 'Test'
```